# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in React Vite in Production

Tags: reactjs, vite, require, referenceerror

I am having issue which says Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.
I am using React 18, Vite version 5. I implemented Vite to my existing React project.
Everything working in dev, but when I build and deploy it into production, I am having this error.
Can anyone help me with it?

I searched everywhere but no success.

[Screenshot for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSzu1.png)

[Screenshot for vite.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w4q5.png)

[Screenshot for folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZlCx.png)

[Screenshot for the package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thzcv.jpg)

Comment: Can you share a reference screenshot ?

Comment: Hey @Utkarsh, I just edited and uploaded screenshot for the error

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Importing modules

When using Vite, use the `import` syntax instead of `require()`

```
// const react = require('react') ❌
import react from 'react' ✅
```

## 2. Referencing assets:

Also, when including images, svgs and videos, replace the `require()` you used to use in create-react-app with the actual path of the asset file.

Example:

```js
// # create-react-app
<img src={require('../media/myImage.png')} /> ❌
```

```
// # Vite
<img src="../media/myImage.png" /> ✅
```

## 3. Importing assets

Sometimes, in your code, you import the assets as modules:

```
import myImage from './myImage'
```

The same happens in Vite.

This is useful when you use path aliases, for instance, sometimes, you import the images in **create-react-app** like this:

```js
<img src={require('@media/myImage.png')} />
```

In vite, if you wanted that, import it first at the top then use it at the bottom:

```js
import MyImage from '@media/myImage.png'
<img src={MyImage} /> ✅
// <img src={"@media/myImage.png"} /> ❌
```

---

Summary: there's nothing called `require()` in vite, if you used to do that in create-react-app, it can't happen in Vite.

Comment: Hey bro thanks for the answer, but I in my code, I never used the word require anywhere. However, after I build my project, in one of my built files, there are the words require, I do not know where they are coming from

Comment: Did you use the VS Code search in all tool function to search for the word "require" ?

Comment: Do you have your project somewhere on github for example?

Comment: Yes, I searched everywhere from vsCode search and my project is private, that is why I cannot share any link

Comment: Also, please note when you serve the files, you're serving them from the ./dist directory and not from the ./build directory. `npx serve -s ./dist`

Comment: if you have seen the screenshot which I attached, the error is coming from file called "App-uoB9xEY3.js" on line "5094:1805", this file is in build folder

Comment: when you use create-react-app, there's a command called `build` in your package.json, it uses a package called `react-scripts` to build your files. The output is in the ./build folder, while in vite, when you build your app, there's a command in your scripts section of your package.json file called `build`, where it uses the command `npx vite build` to build your project, but the output is in the ./dist folder. So perhaps you missed something here.

Comment: `"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },`

Here is my script, how can I create dist folder, I only have build when I run npx vite build

Comment: Hey bro, I also uploaded screenshot for vite.config.js

Comment: Please upload your folder structure as well, use the `tree -L 1 -a ` command and paste that in the answer. or if you're on windows, just use `dir`

Comment: I attached folder structure screenshot above

Comment: And I also uploaded screenshot for package.json

Comment: try deleting the ./build folder, node_modules, and package-lock.json, then re-do `npm i`, and `npm run build`

Comment: I tried but still no success

Comment: Can you share the code _somehow_ so I can test it?

Comment: I would love to but it is very private so I cannot, what I am thinking is that maybe some packages have require used in their code or forgot to import erquire, so when I build it, vite is saying require is not defined, but do not know which package it is